# Sould I build the html up wih only fetch requests?

Tags: javascript

a normal, static html file looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
[..]
<body>
<header>
<!-- here is my header content. -->
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

But often you have multiple Files, obviously every single one with the same header, then you would just include the header with php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
[..]
<body>
<?php
require 'header.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But here you have to make sure, that every single file has the header included via php.
Now here is my question: Would it make sense, to fetch the header via Javascript with the fetch api?
Not only the header of course, but everything.
Thank you!

Comment: Fetching everything with JavaScript is basically the idea about single page applications: The static HTML in those is just a bootstrapping thing to load the required JavaScript which does the actual heavy lifting. Read up on those.

Comment: @JoachimSauer said it all. In theory you could do it, but that would compromise performance which is something you should always avoid. Definitely read up on React.js, Vue.js or Angular.js and you'll see your question makes a lot of sense and is the reason why we had this great jump of webapp quality in the last five years.

Comment: these frameworks seem to be so big and complex, I dont if I am smart enough to learn these...